# Display numerical value associated with each calendar day in month view

Tags: usability, mobile, mobile-web, calendar

What is a good way to show a numerical value associated with a date, and make sure the date and value aren't confusing?

For example if a user wants to see how many meetings they have on each day of the month.

This is my attempt.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very common method of displaying numeric results is a number inside of a circle. You will have seen this with iOS notifications and other web applications.

A quick mockup of what it could look like:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7l6C9.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Something like this is effective at conveying your meaning because it builds upon systems that users are already accustomed to.